# How does the putchar and whole of the code gets executed?

Tags: c, dev-c++, putchar

**I want the dry run of the code for the first 3 iterations to understand**.
THe output of the code is  : abcdbcdbcdbcdbc........(infinte times)

I know how for loop works and put char also.I did not dry run as i was not understand will the third argument in the for loop will increment or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (putchar('a');putchar('b');putchar('d'))
    putchar('c');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `putchar('b')` - this part of the `for` loop should have a condition which should be false (if you want the loop to break).

Comment: 1) have you checked how a `for` loop works? 2) have you checked what `putchar`does? If not, do it. If so, what didn't you understand?

Comment: What is your effort so far? Have you tried a dry run yet? What was your result, what is your expected output and how is this different from what you observed?

Comment: You might want to read [these class notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx3e.html).

Comment: @4386427 PREVIOUSLY I was not unable to understand how this code was working but now i understood .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`putchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) always returns the char that you put. So for instance, `putchar('a')` returns `'a'`. With that in mind, let's have a look at how the [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) loop works:

> for ( init_clause ; cond_expression ; iteration_expression )
>   loop_statement

The `init_clause` is `putchar('a')`. This prints `a` once, because the `init_clause` is evaluated once at the beginning of the `for` loop.

The `cond_expression` is `putchar('b')`. This is checked every run through the loop, which is why it always prints `b`. And as it returns `'b'` every time, the loop never stops. The loop would only stop if the `cond_expression` returned `0` or the loop is exited otherwise, for instance through `break`.

The `iteration_expression` is `putchar('d')`, hence `d` is printed every time. The `loop_statement` is `putchar('c')`, printing `c`.

The result is printing `a` once, followed by an infinite amount of `bcd`. The reason why you get them in this order is because in every run throught the loop, it first checks the `cond_expression`, executes the `loop_statement` and then the `iteration_expression`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**For your example:**

> **Initial statement :** `putchar('a')`
>
> **Condition expression:** `putchar('b')`
>
> **Repeat step:** `putchar('d')`
>
> **Loop statement :** `putchar('c')`

Now map you `code` with flow chart above.

Since `putchar` returns the character it has printed which is `b` also satisfies the `true` condition, thus your for loops run infinite time.

---

> Attribution :
> http://www.equestionanswers.com/c/for-while-do-while-loop-syntax.php

Comment: How my question is too broad . This question is short .